# React-scroll link offset is working fine for larger screen but for smaller screen, its scrolling to a point far beyond the start,with fixed header

Tags: reactjs, offset

With a fixed header, the link on navigation bar is given an offset value so that it scrolls to the start of the section and it is visible. It works fine on larger screen but on smaller screen,it is not working.On smaller screen,its scrolling far beyond the start of the section even more than the height of the fixed header.

```
function Header() {
  const [menuAnchor, setMenuAnchor] = useState(null);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(-90); // Default offset
  const openMenu = (event) => {
    setMenuAnchor(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const closeMenu = () => {
    setMenuAnchor(null);
  };

  const pages = ['About', 'Skills', 'Projects', 'Contact'];
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        // Adjust the offset for smaller screens
        setOffset(-120); 
      } else {
        // Default offset for larger screens
        setOffset(-90);
      }
    };
    // Set initial offset
    handleResize();
    // Update offset on window resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    // Clean up the event listener
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <AppBar
      className='navbar'
      position="fixed"
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
      sx={{ height: '90px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}
    >
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
       
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
              {pages.map((page, index) => (
                <Button
                
                  key={index}
                  sx={{ mx: 2, color: 'black'}}
                >
                  
                 <Link to={page.toLowerCase()} smooth={true} duration={500} offset={offset}>
                      {page}
                 </Link>

                </Button>
             
              ))}
             
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' } }}>
              <IconButton
                edge="end"
                color="black"
                aria-label="menu"
                onClick={openMenu}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                anchorEl={menuAnchor}
                open={Boolean(menuAnchor)}
                onClose={closeMenu}
              >
                {pages.map((page, index) => (
                  <MenuItem
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => {
                      closeMenu();
                      document
                        .getElementById(page.toLowerCase())
                        .scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
                    }}
                  >
                    {page}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Menu>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Its working fine for larger screen but why is it not working for smaller screens.

I have tried giving window.innerwidth as a condition for setting the offset value but still it did not work.